# How to make a countl_zero() but for any type?

Tags: c++, templates, leading-zero

I use in my project such a function for counting leading zeros, the aim for it is to work with any non container type and   to return a constant expression, so that I could use it's results for other templates.

```
template <typename T>
consteval int CountLeadingZeros(const T& DATA) {
    T MASK{ 1 };
    int BITSN{ sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT },
        LEADINGN{ 0 };
    MASK <<= BITSN - 1;
    for (int I = BITSN; I > 0; I--, LEADINGN++, MASK >>= 1) {
        if (DATA & MASK) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return LEADINGN;
}
```

But of cause it doesn't return a real const expression.
If you'll try to use it, there will be an error:

```
    constexpr int value = CountLeadingZeros <const int> (100);
```

Error:

```
E3133 call to consteval function "fsm::CountLeadingZeros(const T &DATA) [with T=const int]" did not produce a valid constant expression
```

On the other hand C++20 countl_zero() works perfect and returns constexpr. But it can not work with anything except uint8_t.

Help me please to fight and win this E3133 error. How could I make my function working in compile time?

Comment: The cppreference documentation for [`countl_zero`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/countl_zero) says it works for types other than `uint8_t`.

Comment: `countl_zero` works with all `uint*_t` types, not just `uint8_t`. Doing what it does for other types is probably undefined behavior or at least implementation dependent.

Comment: [Both GCC and Clang tell you exactly what is wrong with your call](https://godbolt.org/z/eojPPonf6).

Comment: MSVC also tells you what's wrong: "error C3892: 'MASK': you cannot assign to a variable that is const". I don't know what compiler you are using but you might want to switch.

Comment: Unfortunally for modules IntelliSense dosn't always work well. But thank you for an advise to use godbolt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass `const int` as the template argument. Replace it with just `int`. Currently, `MASK` gets declared as `const int MASK = 1`, and then you try to modify it, which obviously doesn't work. Otherwise, the function should be constant-evaluatable

Comment: Thank you very much.
I also changed I > 0 to I > 1 and it worked.

Comment: @Dadunddd.aD If you found my answer helpful, you might want to accept (tick) and/or upvote it

Comment: Sorry, cannot upvote because of low reputation, but accepted

Answer (score 0):

One more solution:

```
template <typename T, typename MASK_TYPE = typename remove_const<T>::type>
constexpr int CountLeadingZeros(const T & DATA) {
    MASK_TYPE MASK{ 1 };
    int BITSN{ sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT},
        LEADINGN{ 0 };
    MASK <<= BITSN - 1;
    for (int I = BITSN; I > 0; I--, LEADINGN++, MASK >>= 1) {
        if (DATA & MASK) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return LEADINGN;
}
```

Or shorter version:

```
template <typename T, typename MASK_TYPE = typename remove_const<T>::type>
constexpr int LeadingN(const T& DATA) {  // returns number of leading zeros in a bit representation
    int BITSN{ sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT }, I{ BITSN };
    MASK_TYPE MASK{ 1u << BITSN - 1 };
    for (; I && !(DATA & MASK); I--, MASK >>= 1) {}
    return BITSN - I;
}
```

Here's the result:
https://github.com/redmms/FineStream/tree/master